# Store a list of messages in an array using individual API calls

Tags: javascript, node.js

So essentially I have a function that makes an API call that gets me a list of message IDs as follows:

```
function getMessageList(auth) {
    api.users.messages.list({
        auth: auth,
        userId: 'me',
    }, function(err, response) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
            return;
        }

        var messages = response.messages;

        if (messages.length == 0) {
            console.log('No messages found.');
        } else {
            console.log('messages:');

            var messageList = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
                var message = messages[i].id;
                getMessage(auth, message, function(response) {
                    messageList.push(response);
                    console.log(messageList);
                });
            }
        }

    });
}
```

And using that ID list I need to make a call for each individual ID to get the message contents as follows:

```
function getMessage(auth, messageId, callback) {
    api.users.messages.get({
        auth: auth,
        userId: 'me',
        id: messageId
    }, function(err, response) {
        if(err) {console.log(err); }
        callback(response);
    });
}
```

Basically, I want to be able to create an array of messages, which I am doing with that callack, but also be able to use it outside the callback function. Probably a bit of a silly question, but I'm a little rusty on my JS.

I thought of putting that loop in a separate function (generateMessageList()) and using a then() promise but I couldn't get that to work... maybe my syntax was off. Here is what it looked like:

```
function generateMessageList(auth, messages) {
    var messageList = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
        var message = messages[i].id;
        getMessage(auth, message, function(response) {
            messageList.push(response);
        });
    }
    return messageList;
}
```

And I'd try `generateMessageList(auth, messages).then(console.log(messageList));` to no avail.

Not sure what the proper way to do this is, any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is asynchronous in nature use promises. A great example is bluebird.So basically wrap with promises then with each the promise will return a object from either a success or error in the catch block from the request. MAKE ANY SENSE?

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');

function generateMessageList(auth, messages) {
function getMessage(auth, messageId) {
return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
    api.users.messages.get({
    auth: auth,
    userId: 'me',
    id: messageId
}, function(err, response) {
    if(err) {reject(err);}
    resolve(response);
});
});

}
```

then in your `generateMessageList(auth, messages)`

```
function generateMessageList(auth, messages) {
var messageList = [];
return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
    var message = messages[i].id;
    var promise = getMessage(auth, message);
promise.then(function(result){   messageList.push(result);}).catch(function(err){reject(err);});
}
resolve(messageList);

 });
```

}

then where ever you are calling `generateMessageList(auth, messages)`

just call then and catch on the returned promise with the list of messages.

Comment: your code as a lot of race conditions currently and very prone to errors.

Comment: but advice is this please remove the loop it makes no sense to individual get ids ,  just do one api call for all message ids and let the api return an array of the messages in stead. this way there will be no race conditions because it will only one array to process.

Comment: Thanks I'll test this in a few minutes, unfortunately, the API seems to only support getting message contents this way (Gmail API)... I agree with you, it'd make a lot more sense just to get all the content this way.

Comment: There is a problem in the generateMessageList() function you wrote: the resolve(messageList) didn't rely on the promise being complete... so I had to make a bit of modifications to get it to work but I managed to figure it out.

Comment: I have added the solution I used to get it working. (I didn't use Bluebird... just native js)

Comment: i figured just to let you know bluebird is a lot faster , well that matters if you are in to efficiency. glad to help.

Comment: Ah, I'll look into bluebird then... thanks for the help... (also the solution seems like it needs be peer reviewed in my OP so it might not appear right away)

Comment: where your from america?

Answer (score 0):

You're doing an async api call in a loop, the result will be there after the loop has finished and messageList will be empty. I would recommend you to get your head arround promises or observables, with them you can easily wait until all your api calls are finished and map the result into an array.

Just a little side-note: Why are you doing one api call per message id, just do one api call for all message ids and let the api return an array of the messages.

Comment: Thanks I'll look into promises and observables. That's exactly what I want to do... wait for the api calls to be finished, just not sure how.

And the API seems to only support it this way... I'd much prefer to just get all the messages. (Gmail API fyi)